# Verification that a function $f(x)$ is probability density function(pdf)

Tags: probability-theory

I calculated the probability density function of the range of $n$  random variables chosen identically and independently with the cumulative distribution $ \mathbf{F}(x)=x^2$   and it came out to be 
$$     
   f(x)=\frac{4n(n-1)}{8x^3}[\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}-x^4(\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{x^{2n-2}}{n-1})],\text{where} \quad n=2,3,..
$$
How can we verify that $f $ is indeed a pdf over the interval  $(0,1)$ for $n=2,3,4,..$.Even a numerical confirmation for particular values of n will do.How can I  computationally verify it in MATHEMATICA  or MATLAB  or something else.That is ,in other words ,can we numerically verify $\int_0^1f(x)dx=1,\text{for}\quad n=2,3,4,....$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a valid PDF. I gave the function to Mathematica to integrate and it produced this:
[image: Integral from 0 to 1, general form]

Substituting $n=2$ yielded an integral of $4.667$:
[image: n=2 example]
You can try plotting the function to see that it grows quite quickly.